# XmlNodeList is empty with NameSpace in C# code

Tags: c#, xml-namespaces, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

I want go into a specific path '/trace/calls/call/userTableParameters/parameter' and take out all parameter names with values. I have used a namespace in xpath while doing xmlnode selection. It returns the right fisrt childnode 'parameter'. but xmlnodelist doesn't return any content further. What would be the problem in my code?

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(@"d:\Drops.xml");

    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("nsTrace", "http://www.polystar.com/OSIX/monitoring/traceSchemaV1.0");
    XmlNode ParameterNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//nsTrace:userTableParameters", nsmgr);
    XmlNodeList ParameterNodeList = ParameterNode.SelectNodes("//parameter");

    foreach (XmlNode node in ParameterNodeList)
            {
                Parameter drop = new Parameter();
                drop.name = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value;
                drop.content = node.InnerText;

                callParameter.ParameterList.Add(drop);
            }


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<trace xmlns="http://www.polystar.com/OSIX/monitoring/traceSchemaV1.0">
    <calls>
        <call>
            <messages>
                <message>
                    <parameters>
                        <parameter name="Timestamp">Wed 11 Nov 2015 11:58:14.096</parameter>
                        <parameter name="Direction">---&gt;</parameter>
                        <parameter name="Resulting Status">Normal</parameter>
                        <parameter name="Resulting State Name">AP Request Pending</parameter>
                        <parameter name="Source Address">11.111.111.11</parameter>
                        <parameter name="Dest Address">11.222.222.22; ABC2</parameter>
                        <parameter name="Media Probe Id"/>
                        <parameter name="Deciphered"/>
                    </parameters>
                </message>  
            </messages>
            <userTableParameters>
                <parameter name="Start Time">11:58:14.096</parameter>
                <parameter name="End Time">11:58:27.191</parameter>
                <parameter name="Duration">00:00:13.095</parameter>
                <parameter name="Date">Wed 11 Nov 2015</parameter>
                <parameter name="Protocol">AP</parameter>
                <parameter name="Status">End</parameter>
                <parameter name="AP II"/>
                <parameter name="AP TI">e0a5e84d'H</parameter>
                <parameter name="AP Cause">3; due-to-generated-reason</parameter>
            </userTableParameters>
        </call>
    </calls>
</trace>
```

Comment: Try including the namespace in all the queries, e.g.
XmlNodeList ParameterNodeList = ParameterNode.SelectNodes("//nsTrace:parameter");

Comment: Another case of namespace overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Xpath query is wrong. 
I also shorten your code.
More information about [Xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp)

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("nsTrace","http://www.polystar.com/OSIX/monitoring/traceSchemaV1.0");
XmlNodeList ParameterNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//nsTrace:userTableParameters//nsTrace:parameter", nsmgr);
```

Comment: this is the trick to identify a correct xpath with namespace! "//nsTrace:userTableParameters//nsTrace:parameter". Is any MSDN or website could provide more examples and definitions?

Comment: actually i shared link(from [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp)) in asnwer . You can also check these pages
[w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath)

[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) @AnsonLeung